# setting up subversion on linux server

Tags: svn

I am trouble setting up subversion for remote access.

I can create a repository in the apache www directory of the server and checkout remotely just fine.

How can I create a repository that is not in the www directory and secure it from access by others.

I am running svnserve. Is there some sort of configuration I need to set or a certain directory for accessing repositories remotely?

Answer (score 2):

I run my SVN server with Apache. I have set up a *svn* subdirectory in my www root that Apache serves using Digest authentication for user authorization. The Subversion user manual has a [detailed section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authn.digest) covering configuration of Apache to do this.

Also, make sure you give write access to your repository to your www-data user (or whatever user you let Apache use). Make sure it is also applied to all the subdirectories (apply it recursively). If you don't you may find you can check out okay, but will have problems checking in.